# How to auto refresh previous page (first page) using flutter_bloc in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

> SCENARIO

There are two pages, first page is HomePage where it fetch the api data automatically with the help of flutter_bloc package. In the homepage (first page) there is also a button which goes to second page (Settings Page) with the help of this code `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SettingsPage()));`. In the Second page there are 3 radiobuttons and one button at the bottom (Button name is Save). And when i click on save button it goes back to homepage with the help of this code `Navigator.pop(context);`

> QUESTION

When i select any of the radiobutton and click on button at the bottom, how do i refresh or rebuild the homepage and fetch the api data again.

Comment: Please go through this article:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data Once you are getting back, just refresh your api call state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the instance of the bloc for the home page to the settings page bloc, and then when you press save, or when you change the options in settings, trigger an event in the home page bloc that fetches the updated data and emits the result in the home page bloc output stream.

Comment: Do you have any examples because i am a beginner in flutter and bloc

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sample code 

'import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

EdgeInsets globalMargin =
const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0);
TextStyle textStyle = const TextStyle(
  fontSize: 100.0,
  color: Colors.black,
);

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int number = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('SO Help'),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            number.toString(),
            style: textStyle,
          ),
          new GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              new InkResponse(
                child: new Container(
                    margin: globalMargin,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: new Center(
                      child: new Text(
                        "+",
                        style: textStyle,
                      ),
                    )),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    number = number + 1;
                  });
                },
              ),
              new Sub(this),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: new Icon(Icons.update),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Sub extends StatelessWidget {

  _MyHomePageState parent;

  Sub(this.parent);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new InkResponse(
      child: new Container(
          margin: globalMargin,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(
              "-",
              style: textStyle,
            ),
          )),
      onTap: () {
        this.parent.setState(() {
          this.parent.number --;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the first page, at the `onPressed` function

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>new PageTwo()),)
    .then((val)=>val?_getRequests():null),
```

Change the values of `_getRequest` to the API call and the page two to the next page.